# Firebase CronJobs - how to allow http triggers from one cronjob site

Tags: firebase, cron, google-cloud-functions, http-authentication

Since Firebase (Real-time DB) does not support cron-jobs I am using [cron-job.org](http://cron-job.org) to schedule http triggers. This function should fire once at the end of every day, so at around 11:55pm. The thing is I would like only cron-job.org to be able to trigger the http endpoint and no one else (e.g. someone malicious trying to trigger it many times a day). How can I achieve this in my cloud function?

I have setup the cronjob and this is all the code I have right now:

```
exports.findAndDeleteSevenDayJobs = functions.https.onRequest((req, res) => {
  console.log('req',req);
});
```

Also, cron-job.org offers this:

[image]

And I have no idea how to use it.

Comment: Nevermind. Solved it by using this: https://github.com/firebase/functions-samples/tree/master/delete-unused-accounts-cron. Attach key to the http request of cron-job and compare within the cloud function using secure-compare.

Comment: And with that you've discovered the secret magic behind API keys Walter. ;-)   Would you mind posting your approach as an answer? It might be useful to others in the future.

Comment: @FrankvanPuffelen Of course, right away!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

To create cron-jobs in firebase RDB use a third party service like [cron-job.org](http://www.cron-job.org)

**1) CREATING THE KEY**

To make everything secure you have to generate a secure key, from now on called `YourSelfGeneratedButSecureKey`.

You can generate one in your terminal by typing: `node -e "console.log(require('crypto').randomBytes(20).toString('hex'))"`

**2) CREATING CRON JOB**

Create a new cron-job that will hit your cloud function end-point and attach the created key as a url-query like so:

`https://{projectSpecific}.cloudfunctions.net/{nameOfFunction}?key={YourSelfGeneratedButSecureKey}`

Setup the key into your env by using the following command in your terminal:
`firebase functions:config:set cron.key="{YourSelfGeneratedButSecureKey}"`

**3) CLOUD FUNCTION**

To make sure everything is maximum security you can install `secure-compare` by typing `npm install --save secure-compare`;

Then in your cloud function:

```
const secureCompare = require('secure-compare');

exports.{nameOfFunction} = functions.https.onRequest((req, res) => {

  const { key } = req.query;

  if (!secureCompare(key, functions.config().cron.key)) {
    console.log('Key in request and in env do NOT match');
    res.status(403).send('Security key does not match.');
    return null;
  }
  
  // DO REPETITIVE STUFF SECURELY 

});
```

Comment: cron-jobs.org - This link is dead. Thank you for showing your solution though. :)

Comment: @hellmit100 Thanks, I updated the link!